# Ehcache3 get time-to-live configuration

Tags: java, ehcache

I'm transitioning from Ehcache2.X to Ehcache3.3.1 and I can't find a way to get the time-to-live configuration for a cache at run-time. Previously I used:
`cache.getCacheConfiguration().getTimeToLiveSeconds()`

Now, it looks like I need to do something akin to:
`cache.getRuntimeConfiguration().getExpiry().getExpiryForCreation().getLength()`

but, `getExpiryForCreation()` requires a key, value pair for a specific element and appears to return the duration for that element.

Am I missing something in the API or docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post here the same answer as on the ehcache mailing list.

An Expiry implementation can be very dynamic and select the expiry time using a given cached key and value.

If you know that you did something like
`Expirations.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.of(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))` 
to create it, then, it won't be dynamic. So you can do
`cache.getRuntimeConfiguration().getExpiry().getExpiryForCreation(null, null)`
to get the duration of a cache entry after creation.

If you then want to dynamically change the TTL, it is possible but you will need to provided your own `Expiry` implementation (not really hard to do). With a setter for the TTL.

However, the new value will only apply to new added entries. Existing entries won't see their TTLs changed. This is because we calculate the expiration timestamp when the entry is added. Instead of reapplying the duration all the time. For performance reasons.